# Need Parent child maven structure in local system

Tags: maven, maven-3, parent-child, parent-pom

I have three maven projects one parent two children, the parent project has only the Super pom, while one child has the launcher class, and other is a web service that requires that launcher class to get started.

I need all these connected in my local system. What should be the structure that I should follow?

Comment: You have already provided a structure in your question, why would be it any different in your local environment? What do you mean by `connected`? Also, I hope one of the of child module has other child module as a dependency.

Answer (score 0):

If one project needs classes from a different jar, just declare a Maven `<dependency>`.